# Android: Find capacity of NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

I am writing NFC application for Android.

Want to find total size of chip (number of bytes writeable) but couldn't find any solutions online.

edit:
I want to find it programmatically

Comment: do you need that programmatically? If no, you can use NFCTagInfo android app on google playstore.

Comment: @VaibhavJain Yes programmatically.